# Need a RegEx that will match a name="value"

Tags: regex

Here's what I have so far, I'm not a regex expert by any means....
I need to be able to match globally.  (/g)

```
total-matched=\"([^\"]*)\"


total-matched="1618"
total-matched= "1618" 
total-matched ="1618" 
total-matched = "1618"
total-matched='1618'
total-matched= '1618'
total-matched ='1618'
total-matched = '1618'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
total-matched\s*=\s*(["'])(.*?)\1
```

- `total-matched` - matched literally
- `\s*` - optional whitespace before `=`
- `=` - matched literally
- `\s*` - optional whitespace after `=`
- `(["'])` - match either type of quote, and remember it as \1
- `(.*?)` - non-greedy match for any text, captured as group 2
- `\1` - match the same kind of quote we matched earlier

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and writing out the reasons.  That makes it easier to figure out whats going on.